# KendoUI- Adding an array to a data source?

Tags: kendo-ui

In KendoUI can you add an array to a data source used in a grid. 
This array is being dynamically generated.

Looking for a way to loop through the elements possibly and assign them.

This is what I want to **avoid**:

```
var movies = [
    { title: "Star Wars: A New Hope", year: 1977 },
    { title: "Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980 },
    { title: "Star Wars: Return of the Jedi", year: 1983 }
];

var localDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: movies });
```

Comment: Any progress with your issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can certainly do that using this method( [example](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-add)) or try below code :

```
var movies = [
    { title: "Star Wars: A New Hope", year: 1977 },
    { title: "Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980 },
    { title: "Star Wars: Return of the Jedi", year: 1983 }
];

var dataSource= new kendo.data.DataSource();

for (var i=0; i<movies.length; i++) {
      dataSource.add(movies[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a file in the data folder called employees.php.

and the following is content of file to written dyanmic data

```
<?php

     $link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Unable To Connect To Database Server");
     mysql_select_db("northwind") or die("Unable To Connect To Northwind");

      $arr = array();

     $rs = mysql_query("SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName FROM Employees");

    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
           $arr[] = $obj;
    }

    echo "{\"data\":" .json_encode($arr). "}";

 ?>
```

and the kendo ui grid example

```
<body> 

    <div id="grid"></div> 

    <script>

        $(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: "data/employees.php"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: "data"
                    }
                },
                columns: [{ field: "FirstName" }, { field: "LastName" }]
            });
        });

    </script> 

</body>
```

hope this will help you

Comment: TS wasn't asking of anything like that